# How to use js parameter and anchor(same page) on a href link

Tags: javascript, html

Every time I click an `<a>` element with an anchor AND a JavaScript parameter, the URL doesn't change, the page just leads me to the anchor element. For example, when I'm on "website.com" and I click this hyperlink:

```
<a href="website.com/?par=123#anchor">TEST</a>
```

The page will scroll to the #anchor element but the URL will still be "website.com", so the JS parameter doesn't get any value. I tried to replace the code with this:

```
<a href="website.com/?par=123#anchor" onclick="window.location.reload(true)">
```

And the page reloads, but it only reloads after scrolling to the #anchor element and it still keeps on "website.com", so no success.

Comment: the GET value (or the location.search variable) should show at the top. It's not a JS variable. You need to write code to parse the url, get that search variable (?par=123) and do something about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the whole purpose of [URL hashes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash). It was initially designed to scroll to a particular `id` in the DOM and was also used by some SPA (Single Page Application) frameworks before the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) existed, as a solution to represent a JavaScript state in the URL.

As it represents a state of the web page **in the browser**, it's **never sent to the server** so the browser doesn't send the request again when it changes because the current URL (and thus the server-side resource) is considered unchanged.

If you want to execute JavaScript code in reaction to the hash change event, you can do like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => console.log(window.location.hash));
```

```html
<a href="#foo">Foo</a>
<a href="#bar">Bar</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I managed to do some workaround here. The solution I was able to find was to add `document.getElementById('anchor').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })` along with the parameter code, inside an "if" condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `par='123#anchor'` instead `par=123#anchor` like this code and it works.

```
   <a href="website.com/?par='123#anchor'">TEST</a>
```